# Pyspark: How to fill null values based on value on another column

Tags: pyspark

I want to fill null values on a Spark df based on the values of the id column.

Pyspark df:

| index | id | animal | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | cat | doug |
| 2 | 002 | dog | null |
| 3 | 001 | cat | null |
| 4 | 003 | null | null |
| 5 | 001 | null | doug |
| 6 | 002 | null | bob |
| 7 | 003 | bird | larry |

Expected result:

| index | id | animal | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | cat | doug |
| 2 | 002 | dog | bob |
| 3 | 001 | cat | doug |
| 4 | 003 | bird | larry |
| 5 | 001 | cat | doug |
| 6 | 002 | dog | bob |
| 7 | 003 | bird | larry |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `last` (or `first`) with window function.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('id')
df = (df.withColumn('animal', F.last('animal', ignorenulls=True).over(w))
      .withColumn('name', F.last('name', ignorenulls=True).over(w)))
```